# Zooming UIImageView in UIScrollView goes out of bounds

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I've successfully implemented zooming of `UIImageView` in my `UIScrollView` but I have faced with a strange problem that irritates me.

Basically, when I zoom in the image

[image]

I can pan the view to actually scroll out of the image border and I'm left with a black area like this:
[image]

And as I zoom in more I can make the black border to fill the whole screen!
Meanwhile in the iPhone Photo app you can't zoom out the actual image. What's wrong here in my implementation?

It looks like this:

```
UIImage *imageToDisplay = [UIImage imageWithData:tmpImageData];
imageViewMain.image = imageToDisplay;
imageViewMain.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollViewMain.frame.size.width, scrollViewMain.frame.size.height);
imageViewMain.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

scrollViewMain.delegate = self;
scrollViewMain.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
scrollViewMain.maximumZoomScale = 9.0;
scrollViewMain.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
scrollViewMain.contentSize = imageViewMain.frame.size;

[self.view addSubview:scrollViewMain];
[scrollViewMain addSubview:imageViewMain];
```

And I also implement this method:

```
- (UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return imageViewMain;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
When I first load the view I shrink my UIImageView to fit the scroll view and the image looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Why you use scrollview you can you UIPinchGestureRecognizer for zooming the image

Comment: @SAMIRRATHOD Will your stinky gesture recogniser allow me to drag the imageView here and there? I highly doubt it, sir.

Comment: yes, you can drag your imageview using GestureRecognizer

Comment: @SAMIRRATHOD I assure you, that using UIScrollView is a better way to do this.

Comment: Sergious: Maybe this [GitHib project](https://github.com/patelrohan/ZoomImage) can help you. Please give it a try. I did not looked at the full code at yours so just suggesting link.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? @SergiusGee

Comment: @lostAstronaut Yes, indeed I did, but it was my own custom implementation of `UIScrollView`

Comment: Any chance you could post it?

Comment: I have a question very similar, and I believe you could answer it easily as you fixed it yourself.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246753/uiscroll-center-image  Also I'm putting a bounty on it in a few hours, but feel free to answer before and I can always award it after.

Answer (score 2):

Just try this code.... change some code where it required... use `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` for your `UIImageView` and then add this image in your `UIScrollView` like bellow..

```
UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
img.image = [UIImage imageWithData:tmpImageData];
img.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
img.frame = CGRectMake(210,100, 200, 200);/// define frame which you want...
[img sizeToFit];

UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scale:)];
[pinchRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[img addGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizer];
[pinchRecognizer release];
[scrollViewMain addSubview:img];
[scrollViewMain bringSubviewToFront:img];
[img release];
```

and just paste this bellow code in your .m file...

```
#pragma mark GestureRecognizer Methods
-(void)scale:(id)sender 
{
    UIView *imgTempGest = [sender view];
    if([(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) 
    {
        lastScale = 1.0;
        return;
    }
    CGFloat scale = 1.0 - (lastScale - [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender scale]);

    CGAffineTransform currentTransform = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender view].transform;
    CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(currentTransform, scale, scale);

    [[(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender view] setTransform:newTransform];

    [imgTempGest setTransform:newTransform];

    lastScale = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender scale];
}
```

Here for LastScale just define that variable in `.h` file like bellow...

```
CGFloat lastScale;
```

i hope this helpful to you...

Comment: As far as I'm concerned this will not let me 'drag' the image around, right?

Comment: No this code helpful to zoom-in zoom-out the UIImage but if you want to drag and drop image then for that another code required dude..

Comment: Well then, your answer is wrong. And that's why I'm using a scrollView. To scroll the content and not only zoom it!

Comment: dude for that you must provide two facility to the image here not work  whole facility with your one code.. this code zoom-in,zoom-out your image and for drag and drop i have another code which is also drag-drop your same image , both working.

Comment: What kind of facility, sorry?

Comment: That's a different way to do this. I hope to implement it using UIScrollView

Comment: see here you want to use scrollview then its fine but if you want to zoom-in zoom out only image then you must use above concept otherwise you use scrollview's minimumZoomScale and maximumZoomScale thats..

Comment: @SergiusGee just try my code and then post if you want to another code for drag and drop image on your scrollview and upvote it if now its some helpful to you...

Answer (score 1):

Is the original image contains that border in top and bottom?. You can use the same code over there the output is not wrong if the actual image contains that black top and bottom black area. And add this code also,

> scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES

also change,

> scrollView.contentSize = imageView.bounds.size;

Also you are providing a zoom scale of 9. That much is needed for you?. Change it to 3 or 4 and try. Your problem will be fixed