# UIScroll center image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I've edited this question a few times, but can still not get my images to center inside a uiview.  I want them to be able to rotate like the photos app and display the correct size when a user brings them up.  Here is what I'm working with:

In my PhotoViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol PhotoViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)toggleChromeDisplay;

@end


@interface PhotoViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>


@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *photo;
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger num;


//Delegate
@property (nonatomic, strong) id<PhotoViewControllerDelegate> photoViewControllerDelegate;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *photoImgView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIScrollView *scrollView;



@end
```

In my PhotoViewController.m:

```
#import "PhotoViewController.h"

@interface PhotoViewController ()

@end

@implementation PhotoViewController


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        //todo

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CGRect screenBounds = self.view.bounds;


    //scroll view
    _scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenBounds.size.width, screenBounds.size.height)];
    _scrollView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
    _scrollView.pagingEnabled = NO;
    _scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    [_scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

    //Zoom Properties
    _scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 6.0;
    _scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
    _scrollView.bouncesZoom = YES;
    _scrollView.delegate = self;
    _scrollView.zoomScale = 1.0;
    _scrollView.contentSize = _photoImgView.bounds.size;
    [_scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
    [_scrollView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
    [self photoBounds];


    [self.view addSubview: _scrollView];


    //Add the UIImageView
    _photoImgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:_photo];
    _photoImgView.image = _photo;
    _photoImgView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    _photoImgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    _photoImgView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin);
    [_photoImgView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    [_scrollView addSubview: _photoImgView];


    //Set up Gesture Recognizer
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapGestureCaptured:)];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *dTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dTapGestureCaptured:)];

    dTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    [singleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:dTap];

    //Gesture Methods
    [self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
    [self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer : dTap];
}





- (void)photoBounds
{

    UIInterfaceOrientation statusbar = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    CGSize photoBounds = _photo.size;
    CGSize scrollBounds = self.view.bounds.size;
    CGRect frameToCenter = [_photoImgView frame];

    float newHeight = (scrollBounds.width / photoBounds.width) * photoBounds.height;
    float newWidth = (scrollBounds.height / photoBounds.height) * photoBounds.width;
    float yDist = fabsf(scrollBounds.height - newHeight) / 2;
    float xDist = fabsf(scrollBounds.width - newWidth) / 2;


    //Width Larger
    if (photoBounds.width >=photoBounds.height) {

        NSLog(@"portrait width");
        _photoImgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollBounds.width, newHeight);
        frameToCenter.origin.y = yDist;

    }

    //Height Larger
    else if (photoBounds.height > photoBounds.width) {

        NSLog(@"portrait height");
        _photoImgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, newWidth, scrollBounds.height);
        frameToCenter.origin.x = xDist;

    }

    //Square
    else {

        NSLog(@"portrait square");
        if ((statusbar == 1) || (statusbar == 2)) {
            _photoImgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollBounds.width, newHeight);
            frameToCenter.origin.y = yDist;

        } else {

            _photoImgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, newWidth, scrollBounds.height);
            frameToCenter.origin.x = xDist;
        }

    }

}




//Rotation Magic
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    //later
}

- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [self photoBounds];
}

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    //
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}



//Zoom Ability
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return self.photoImgView;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(CGFloat)scale
{
    NSLog(@"scale %f", scale);
    NSLog(@"done zooming");



}




//Touches Control
- (void)singleTapGestureCaptured:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    //CGPoint touchPoint=[gesture locationInView:_scrollView];
    NSLog(@"touched");
    NSLog(@"single touch");
    [self performSelector:@selector(callingHome) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];

}

- (void)dTapGestureCaptured:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{

    NSLog(@"double touched");
}

- (void)panGestureCaptured:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{

    NSLog(@"pan gesture");

}


- (void)callingHome {}

@end
```

The overall issue is that I can not get my picture to display correctly and be able to zoom on just it, no space around it and It needs to be the correct dimensions on load.  I've been struggling with it for a few days.

Any help?

Comment: A `UIScrollView` can handle pan gesture itself. Why are your set `_scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;`?

Comment: What is the content size actually set to? It looks like you might be not setting it.

Comment: Mb your gestureRecognizers disturb native scrollView gestureRecognizers...

Comment: @liuyaodong that was defiantly part of my issue, any idea how to set it so I can only zoom on the image as opposed to the whole frame?

Comment: Just go through this tutorial, it will teach you what you need: http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content

Comment: Yea that's not seeming to help much, i've read it probably 10 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved a similar problem using a really simple subclass of UIScrollView of my own. You can take a look at it here - https://gist.github.com/ShadeApps/5a29e1cea3e1dc3df8c8. Works like charm for me.

That's how you init it:

```
scrollViewMain.delegate = self;
scrollViewMain.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
scrollViewMain.maximumZoomScale = 3.0;
scrollViewMain.contentSize = imageViewMain.frame.size;
scrollViewMain.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
scrollViewMain.tileContainerView = imageViewMain;
```

Comment: Great! I'll check it out when I get home.

Comment: @lostAstronaut it can't be easier - you specify the `tileContainerView` property to be your `UIImageView` and there you go. You then add a subclassed scroll view to your view and it should be ready for you. See my edit.

Comment: Wow, much easier than I thought.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

There is awesome blog post about this problem from Peter Steinberger: http://petersteinberger.com/blog/2013/how-to-center-uiscrollview/